# encoding - Avoid repeating characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, math, encoding

I'd like to encode an Integer into a String using 4 different Bits ( A, B, C, D):

Therefore I've wrote a simple **Int to customBase conversion** you can find here:

```
function messageToCustomBase(message, charset) {
   var base = charset.length,
      integer = message,
      result = ""
   do {
        var index = integer % base
    result = charset[index] + result
    integer = parseInt(integer/base)
    } while (integer > 0)
  return result   
}
```

The code is working quite fine and **encoding looks like this**:

```
0 --> "A"
1 --> "B"
2 --> "C"
...
100 --> "BCBA"
...
10000 --> "CBDABAA"
```

But **due to a special program**, I am practically **forced to use a special encode algorithm** which converts the integer to a string which ...

```
1. should have as small a length as possible

2. uses maximum four different letters (4 different bits -> A, B, C, D)

3. Prevents never having the same letters next to each other

   "ABADADA" -> legit
   "ABCDAD" -> legit
   "BABCA" -> legit
   "CDDABC" -> not legit (because of "D" "D")
   "BBBACAB" -> not legit (because of "B" "B" "B")
```

---

**Question**: > How can I avoid multiple characters following each other by editing my messageToBase function?

---

**Example**: Encoding **Integer 42** will give the result "CCC".
Because in my special case "CCC" is not valid it should be encoded different (maybe to e.g. "CBCDCA", ...)

---

**Note**: The string must be able to be decoded later on so just adding random fill-characters between repeating characters after the decoding will not be a working solution.

**Note**: [Here you can find a working fiddle for the base en/decoding](https://jsfiddle.net/6cg14qby/34/)

---

**Edit**: Theoretically we have to add in cases where it comes to repeating letters an additional bit ("E"). Otherwise it will just lead to complications with other Integers!

So I really got no clue how to fix this problem and any help would be very appreciated. :)

Comment: how about converting to base-3 and use the 4th letter as a separator (and simply drop it when decoding)?

Comment: One of my first thoughts also @georg - but this will probably double the length of the encoded string! **Because of this behavior I'm looking for a different method!**

Comment: What would be the desired output for `messageToCustomBase(5,"ABCD")`?

Comment: (Currently the output is "BB".) Therefore a desired output should be as short as possible but should not be get the same output as another encoded int! **Edit: Theoretically you have to explicitly in cases where it comes to repeating letters yet an additional bit ("E") install. Otherwise it will lead to complications with other Ints!** (So the desired output "**could**" be something like "BEB" or "BCEB" or "etc") @DanielBeck

Answer (score 0):

Here's a (rather brute-force) solution:

This simply iterates over your existing encoder with higher "bit depth" until it finds a solution without repeated letters.  The encoding depth is prepended to the encoded value (otherwise it would be impossible to reverse the calculation, because you wouldn't have any way of knowing whether "BA" means 2 (encoded to depth B) or 3 (encoded to depth C).

This doesn't guarantee the lowest possible "bit depth", but it does keep the strings as short as possible given your encoding method.

Here's a demonstration of encoding and decoding numbers from 1 through 50:

```js
var encode = function(number) {
  if (number == 1) {
    return "A-A"; // hacky workaround for endless loop in messageToCustomBase
  }
  var ret = "";
  var bits = Math.floor(Math.log2(number) + 1); // minimum depth required for this number
  var chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

  for (var i = bits; i < 26; i++) {
    var bitIdentifier = chars.charAt(i - 1);
    var encoded = messageToCustomBase(number, chars.substr(0, i));
    if (encoded.match(/(.)\1/)) {
      // duplicate letters found, keep looking
    } else {
      return bitIdentifier + "-" + encoded
    }
  }
}

var decode = function(m) {
  if (m === 'A-A') {
    return 1
  } // hack again
  var chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
  var parts = m.split('-');
  var charset = chars.substr(0, parts[0].charCodeAt(0) - 64);
  return customBaseToMessage(parts[1], charset)
}

// exactly as your original code:
function messageToCustomBase(message, charset) {
  var base = charset.length,
    integer = message,
    result = ""
  do {
    var index = integer % base
    result = charset[index] + result
    integer = parseInt(integer / base)
  } while (integer > 0)
  return result
}

function customBaseToMessage(message, charset) {
  var base = charset.length,
    result = 0
  for (var i = 0; i < message.length; i++)  {
    var index = charset.indexOf(message[i])
    result = result * base + index
  }
  return result
}

// encode numbers for testing:
for (var i = 1; i < 51; i++) {
  console.log(i, encode(i), decode(encode(i)));
}
```

Comment: Hey Daniel. Thanks for your answer - I will have to try it on my own later on. I will respond to your solution then :)

Comment: So hey Daniel - I had a look on your solution - nice way to encode/ decode integers but you are using 26 different bits (A-Z) to encode the identifier. I just like to use 4 different bits! Maybe you like to update your answer- Thanks for your answer anyway :)

Comment: Not quite; this uses a *maximum* of 26 bits for your encoding method. When possible it uses lower amounts. As we established earlier some numbers can’t be encoded this way using only four bits (the number 5 for example).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by sticking to base 3 after the first loop, where the characters available are the three you didn't use for the previous character.

As a modification of your encoding code, this looks like

```
function messageToCustomBase(message, charset) {
  var base = charset.length,
      integer = message,
      result = "",
      previous_index = null

  var index = integer % base
  result = charset[index] + result
  integer = parseInt(integer/base)
  previous_index = index

  while (integer > 0) {
    var index = integer % (base - 1)
    if (index >= previous_index) {
      index++
    }
    result = charset[index] + result
    integer = parseInt(integer/(base - 1))
    previous_index = index
  }
  return result   
}
```

This is pretty close to optimal, but not quite. The reason is that the index for the left-most character will never be zero. Basically, it's doing a "correct" conversion to base (3..4), and is refusing to have representations that start with 0. If you're willing to forgo that, you can get a bit shorter on average.